How to fix classpath not found issue for frodo-plugin in android java
Getting following error in Android Studio Logcat.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyTestProject'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-plugin:0.8.3.
Searched in the following locations:
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/fernandocejas/frodo/frodo-plugin/0.8.3/frodo-plugin-0.8.3.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fernandocejas/frodo/frodo-plugin/0.8.3/frodo-plugin-0.8.3.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/fernandocejas/frodo/frodo-plugin/0.8.3/frodo-plugin-0.8.3.pom
- https://maven.google.com/com/fernandocejas/frodo/frodo-plugin/0.8.3/frodo-plugin-0.8.3.pom
- https://dl.google.com/com/fernandocejas/frodo/frodo-plugin/0.8.3/frodo-plugin-0.8.3.pom

